# Confused about Spring Security Jwt token builder - why do I have to pass headers and claims?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a scenario where a get an access token in my service, and then want to store this in Springs SecurityContextHolder. This is what I'm currently doing

```
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
    String accessToken =  cognitoService.AccessToken();
    Authentication authentication =
            new JwtAuthenticationToken(Jwt.withTokenValue(accessToken)
                    .header("alg", "none")
                    .claim("scope", "message:read")
                    .build());
    context.setAuthentication(authentication);
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
```

This works fine, but what I'm confused about is the fact that I have to pass both header and claim when creating the token.
I'm thinking that both of those are already in the token I pass to .withTokenValue(...), so why do I have to specify them again? When I try doing this:

```
Jwt.withTokenValue(accessToken).build()
```

I get an exception complaining that I have to pass headers. (and if I pass headers, another exception saying I have to pass claims).

Feels like I'm missing something here? Can someone clarify?

Comment: JWT authentication tokens are id tokens and not access tokens. In this example you are using an access token (from cognito service)  to create an ID token. Perhaps it might be the reason for asking headers and claims.

Comment: Maybe the code is confusing, but if you look closer you will see the the code I'm asking about specifically just creates a JWT. It could be an ID token or an access token. I happen to pass the value of an access token. But regardless of type, the headers will still be in the token value, which is what I can't understand.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same conundrum. Digging inside the Spring Security code, it looks like the way to do this is by using an implementation of `org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder`.

In my case, I have a duel security config setup that accepts tokens from Cognito and my own JWT provider which uses Nimbus Jose. I used the Spring config based `JwtDecoder` for the external system and I added a hand made `NumbusJwtDecoder` inside my custom "JwtProvider"...here's a sample of what you can do:

```
import com.nimbusds.jose.*;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.MACSigner;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.MACVerifier;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;


byte[] secretBytes = myTokenSecretString.getBytes();
MACSigner macSigner = new MACSigner(secretBytes);

//I have the following as class members in my real code
JWSSigner signer = macSigner;
JWSVerifier verifier = new MACVerifier(secretBytes);
JwtDecoder jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(macSigner.getSecretKey()).build();
```

From here, all you really need is

```
 Jwt jwt = jwtDecoder.decode(myJwtString);
```

And now you don't need to worry about manually trying to piece together a JWT instance.

As for the Cognito parser, I'm using the following config to have Spring generate the JwtDecoder for me.

requires dependency: `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/${security.oauth2.user-pool}/.well-known/jwks.json
```

Then you can just autowire in the `JwtDecoder`for your inbound Cognito tokens and call the same `jwtDecoder.decode(jwtString)`to get the `Jwt`.